# Will change tracking continue to work if a new table is renamed to original table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, change-tracking

I have a scenario where change tracking is enabled on a Table (say tblABC). This table has IDENTITY set on its primary key column (ID). I plan to remove the IDENTITY spec from this column. The best way suggested to do this is an ALTER TABLE..SWITCH TO, but this process involves new table to be created and renamed back to original table name like so.

```
EXEC sys.sp_rename 'Original2', 'Original', 'OBJECT';
```

I'm not sure if renaming a new table to original name will still keep the change tracking on it. Can a new table be renamed such that change tracking is not lost?

Comment: why not just enable change tracking on the new table when you're finished with your changes

Comment: This seems easy enough to test on a scratch database or table. I would guess that something is going to break in the process but setting up the test is going to take less than five minutes so there's no need to guess - find the answer empirically.

Comment: Sounds like it's probably better to just disable change tracking on the old table, do the switch/renames then set up change tracking again using `HISTORY_TABLE = YourExistingHistory`

Answer (score -1):

You can remove identity from the design view.

1. Right-click on the table and select Design
2. Then select the identity column
3. After that, in the column property tab at the bottom expend identity specification
4. Then select No for (Is Identity) row
5. Save the changes.

> If you are seeing the Save (Not Permitted) Dialog Box then on the
> Tools menu, click Options, expand Designers, and then click Table and
> Database Designers. Select or clear the Prevent saving changes that
> require the table to be re-created check box.

From [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/save-not-permitted-dialog-box?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: If this answer was helpful pleaser accept it to mark the question as answered.